# NSTimer not firing when NSMenu is open in Swift

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, nstimer, nsrunloop

I have a timer that runs to restart an alarm once it goes off.

```
alarm = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
    60 * minutesConstant + secondsConstant,
    target:self,
    selector: Selector("endSession"),
    userInfo: nil,
    repeats:false)
```

Its selector function sets a mode flag, and calls the original function that set the alarm with new minutes and seconds constants, and also sends a user notification that the session has restarted.

I have a menu item that gets updated with the remaining time

[image]

So I've been opening it to check that my alarm does indeed restart, and that the notification shows once it hits zero. It works, but when I have the menu open and it gets down to zero it just stays at 0:00 and the timer doesn't fire until I click off the menu at which point it immediately shows the notification and resets the timer like intended.

How can I force the timer to fire when the menu is open? It's not a big deal but I don't want the user to be confused with the session just hangs if they watch the timer go down.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You just have to add your timer to the main runloop as follow:

**Swift 4.2**

```
RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)
```

**Swift 3**

```
RunLoop.main.add(alarm, forMode: .commonModes)
```

---

**Swift 2.x**

```
NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(alarm, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
```

Comment: This is correct. It's basically what you can see in the airport menu as it periodically scans for SSIDs

Comment: In particular, the run loop is running in the `NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode` during menu tracking. If your timer is only in the `NSDefaultRunLoopMode`, it will not fire. Both of those modes are in the `NSRunLoopCommonModes` set, so adding the timer to that pseudo-mode allows it to fire in both cases (and others).

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the response and clear explanation!

Comment: In Swift 3 it's correct solution: `RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)`

Comment: I have experimenting with my app (I have exported it and ran as a normal app). I have found that it's incorrect work with timer when I leave my app in the background running - it starts to work with delay, and after some time - freezes. It looks like that this solution doesn't work.

Comment: You mean your solution doesn't work. Feel free to open a new question showing your code, how you are measuring time, what you are expecting and the results you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in MacOS using NSOpenPanel. My problem was a timer used for TCP keep-alive which would not fire, and I would lose connection with my devices if the panel was open too long. My app would reconnect once I closed the panel, but was now in the wrong state. Just adding the code as recommended above fixed the problem.

```
RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)
```