# How to keep an OS X menulet application timer running?

Tags: macos, swift, nstimer, menubar

I'm making a menulet (Application that hangs out in the menu bar) using Swift and in that application I have a timer.

Every time I click the menu bar item to reveal the menu, the timer pauses. How can I keep the timer active while the menubar is open?

Comment: How have you implemented that timer?

Comment: Yes, I did. It works fine until I reveal the menu. When I open the menu it pauses. When i close the menu it resumes.

Comment: You haven't answered my question. *How is the timer implemented in your application?* Show us the code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27997485/nstimer-not-firing-when-nsmenu-is-open-in-swift/27997548#27997548

Comment: @James I have already answered the same question and I shouldn't answer it twice. So just up vote it :)