# Refreshing of Menu Bar View when NSMenu is opened

Tags: swift, refresh, menubar

I am developing an app, that has a custom view in the menu bar. The menu bar extra is a custom NSView that is redrawn every second.
When I open the NSMenu of the view, the view freezes and no longer redraws itself. I am using

```
self.graph.needsDisplay = true
```

to trigger a redraw.

Is it possible to refresh a NSView in the menu bar when the NSMenu is opened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turns out it was a duplicate of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27997485/nstimer-not-firing-when-nsmenu-is-open-in-swift)

The solution is to add the timer to the RunLoop:

```
RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .commonModes)
```