# Displaying Live Time Label in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, time

My time label is displaying the time, when I open my app but it won't update it live. I had a look at other answers but they didn't make sense.

```
// CURRENT TIME

    @IBOutlet weak var currentTimeLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getCurrentTime()
    }

// FORMAT TIME

func getCurrentTime(){
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
        let str = formatter.string(from: Date())
        currentTimeLabel.text = str
    }
```

I want my app to update the time label live. Thanks in advance. It's probably a really simple fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `Timer` with repeating every minute (because you don't need seconds for anything) starting in the next minute (so call `getCurrentTime()` once before you start `Timer`).

Every minute code inside `timer`'s closure gets executed so you can say that you want to call `getCurrentTime()`. Now your `currentTimeLabel` will be updated every minute

```
let now = Date()
let date = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: now), minute: Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: now) + 1, second: 0, of: now)!
let timer = Timer(fire: date, timeInterval: 60, repeats: true) { _ in
    self.getCurrentTime()
}
```

---

Also I would recommend you to have `formatter` variable outside of the method (in global scope)

```
lazy var formatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm" // or "hh:mm a" if you need to have am or pm symbols
    return formatter
}()
```

and then in `getCurrentTime()` just get `String` and change `text` of `currentTimeLabel`

```
func getCurrentTime() {
    currentTimeLabel.text = formatter.string(from: Date())
}
```

Comment: If OP’s method has to be called every second, it would be better to have the date formatter initialization outside of the method. Better resource-wise.

Comment: Thanks. Stupid question but where would I add this code?

Comment: @J.Kearney where you want to start Timer. So for example to `viewDidLoad`

Comment: @RobertDresler yes viewDidLoad.

Comment: note that hh is for 01-12. It is missing the am/pm notation. the correct would be `"h:mm a"` or for 24h clock `"HH:mm"
`

Comment: @RobertDresler Worked! Thanks heaps mate

Comment: Btw You should use timeStyle instead of a fixed time format. That should be defined by the user settings/locale.

Comment: Also why would you repeat the timer 60 times per second if the minute changes only every 60 seconds?

Comment: @LeoDabus because when timer starts in let's say 12:16:05 then next update will be in 12:17:05

Comment: You can use fireAt and make it start the next even second

Comment: `func activateTimer() {
    let now = Date()
    let date = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: now),
                             minute: Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: now) + 1,
                             second:  0,
                             of: now)!
    timer = Timer(fireAt: date, interval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)
}`

Comment: this way the timer will be synced with the device'
s clock

Comment: timeInterval: 60

Comment: @LeoDabus is `RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common) }` necessarily?

Comment: I don't think so in your code as it is (using the trailing closure). If it works without it you don't need kkk

Comment: This will save a lot of battery.

Comment: @LeoDabus okay. Thank you so much! Your advices move me forward! :-)

Comment: you are welcome. dont forget to update the time on view did load otherwise it might take a long time to display it at first

Comment: @LeoDabus I think I wrote it into brackets

Comment: Regarding the common mode it its always a good idea to add the timer to the common mode because allows it to fire in all modes. The timer might not fire under certain circumstances which would look like the clock/timer it is not working. This is more evident when coding for macOS and the user clicks the file menu. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27997548/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus yes, I'm using it for example when I need to scroll `UITableView` and I also need cells be updated in every time period.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Timer` for your requirement,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var currentTimeLabel: UILabel!

    var timer = Timer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getCurrentTime()
    }

    private func getCurrentTime() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector:#selector(self.currentTime) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func currentTime() {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
        currentTimeLabel.text = formatter.string(from: Date())
    }
}
```